# Is it possible to access to value of a depedency property in the same user control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a dependency property in a user control, it is a bool that I want to use to hide or show a button according to its value.

My dependency property is this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Enable", typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyView), new PropertyMetadata(false);
public bool Enable
{
    get
    {
        return (bool)GetValue(EnableProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(EnableProperty, value);
    }
}
```

My user control

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="Enable" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

My main user control that uses the user control

```
<views:MyView DataContext="{Binding MyDataContext}"
                        Enable="True"/>
```

But the button is not shown when I set the dependency property as true. I guess the problem is that I don't know how to access to a dependency property of the user control.

Comment: `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" ...>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use  a [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=net-5.0) binding to the parent `MyView` user control, otherwise the binding will try to resolve the `Enable` property on the current data context, where it is not defined.

```
<Button.Style>
   <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyView}}}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the user control like this:

MyControl.xaml

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="ThisControl">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click me">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enable, ElementName=ThisControl}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: @Clemens my bad. I've changed the solution to using `ElementName` to find the property instead of setting the `DataContext` of the control.